# how to remove all even integers from set<int> in c++

Tags: c++, set, stdset

I'm new to C++. I'd like to know how experienced coders do this.

what I have:

```
set<int> s;
s.insert(1);
s.insert(2);
s.insert(3);
s.insert(4);
s.insert(5);

for(set<int>::iterator itr = s.begin(); itr != s.end(); ++itr){
if (!(*itr % 2))
    s.erase(itr);
}
```

and of course, it doesn't work. because itr is incremented after it is erased.
does it mean Itr has to point to the begin of the set everytime after i erase the element from the set?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
 for(set<int>::iterator itr = s.begin(); itr != s.end(); ){
  if (!(*itr % 2))
      s.erase(itr++);

  else ++itr;
 }
```

effective STL by Scott Myers

Comment: why is itr++ allowed in the erase function, but not outside?

Comment: `itr++` is allowed outside, but `++it` is in general preferable when the value is unused, for reasons way to tedious to go into every single time anyone does it ;-) In this case, it might be better to ignore the usual good practice and write `itr++`, just because the code reads slightly smoother if it's the same in both cases.

Answer (score 11):

Erasing an element from std::set only invalidates iterators pointing to that element.

Get an iterator to the next element before erasing the target element.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to go back to the start. `set::erase` only invalidates iterators that refer to the item being erased, so you just need to copy the iterator and increment before erasing:

```
for(set<int>::iterator itr = s.begin(); itr != s.end();)
{
    set<int>::iterator here = itr++;
    if (!(*here % 2))
        s.erase(here);
}
```

Comment: OK, I give up. What's the bug?

Comment: I was wrong, I thought you were skipping the first element. I take back my comment and downvote.

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to use the combination of remove_if and erase

```
s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), evenOddFunctor), s.end())
```

This will be helpful
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove

Also Refer to effective STL by scott meyers

`Edit`: Although my solution is wrong i am not deleting it. It might be a good learning for someone like me who does not about mutable/immutable iterators

Comment: `remove_if` requires that `operator*` returns an non-const lvalue. std::set enforces that it's always ordered; returning a non-const lvalue from `std::set::operator*` would break that guarantee. Therefore `std::remove_if()` does not take `std::set::iterator`s

Comment: That was actually helpful. I've been stuck trying to do this with remove_if and this told me what the issue was. Thanks.

Comment: @AdeMiller Me too. [I hate `remove_if`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16369674/111307).