# std::remove_if - lambda, not removing anything from the collection

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, remove-if, erase-remove-idiom

Ok, I expect I've made a dumb mistake here.  I have a list of DisplayDevice3d and each DisplayDevice3d contains a list of DisplayMode3d.  I want to remove all items from the list of DisplayDevice3d that don't have any DisplayMode3d's.  I'm trying to use a Lambda to do it, ie.:

```
    // If the device doesn't have any modes, remove it.

  std::remove_if(MyDisplayDevices.begin(), MyDisplayDevices.end(),
   [](DisplayDevice3d& device) 
   { 
    return device.Modes.size() == 0; 
   }
  );
```

Even though out of 6 DisplayMode3d's in MyDisplayDevices, only 1 has any DisplayMode3d's in its Modes collection, nothing is being removed from the list.

What numpty mistake have I made here?

Edit:

Ah ok, my mistake was I should be using MyDisplayDevices.remove_if instead of std::remove_if, however the answers below are correct for use of std::remove_if :p.

```
MyDisplayDevices.remove_if( [](DisplayDevice3d const & device) 
                            { 
                                return device.Modes.size() == 0; 
                            });
```

Comment: If the container itself supports remove_if then by all means use it. I believe this is the case with std::list. For containers, that don't offer remove_if, you can use std::remove_if in combination with the container's erase member function.

Comment: @sellibitze In other words, rat poison

Comment: possible duplicate of [Erasing elements from a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need to call erase on the iterator returned from remove_if, It should look something like this:

```
auto new_end = std::remove_if(MyDisplayDevices.begin(), MyDisplayDevices.end(),
                              [](const DisplayDevice3d& device)
                              { return device.Modes.size() == 0; });

MyDisplayDevices.erase(new_end, MyDisplayDevices.end());
```

Answer (score 23):

`remove_if` doesn't remove anything from list it just moves them to end. You need to use it along with `erase`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347441/erasing-elements-from-a-vector) for more details.

Comment: So I erase from the iterator it returns to the end of the list?

Comment: @Troyseph: The things that you want to keep are moved to the front (via assignment). Nothing is moved to the back. The stuff you don't need anymore is just there at the end and can be erased.

Answer (score 16):

`remove_if` doesn't perform resizing, but instead it just returns the iterator to the element that follows the last element not removed. This iterator can be passed to `erase()` to do the clean up.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there are ways to make it work.  However my advice would be to completely avoid `remove_if` and stick to a standard iterator-based removal instead.  The idiom below works both for `list` and `vector` and does not produce unexpected behavior.

```
for( vector<TYPE>::iterator iter = vec.begin() ; iter != vec.end() ; )
  if( iter->shouldRemove )
    iter = vec.erase( iter ) ; // advances iter
  else
    ++iter ; // don't remove
```

As the comments below mention, this method does have a higher cost than `remove_if` when more than 1 element is removed.

`remove_if` works by copying elements from further ahead in the vector, and overwriting vectors that should be removed from the vector by the one immediately in front of it. For example: remove_if called on a vector to remove all 0 elements:

```
0 1 1 0 1 0
```

results in:

```
1 1 1 0 1 0
```

Notice how the vector isn't correct yet. That is because `remove_if` returns an iterator to the last valid element... it doesn't automatically resize the vector. You still need to call `v.erase()` on the iterator returned from your call to `remove_if`.

An example is below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

void print( vector<int> &v )
{
  for( int i : v )
    printf( "%d ", i );
  puts("");
}

int main()
{
  vector<int> v = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
  print( v ); // 0 1 1 0 1 0
  vector<int>::iterator it = remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), [](int i){ return i == 0; } );
  print( v ); // 1 1 1 0 1 0
  v.erase( it, v.end() ); // actually cut out values not wanted in vector
  print( v ); // 1 1 1 (correct)
}
```

Comment: Why would you recommend this method over *remove_if()*? Surely *remove_if()* doesn't produce "unexpected behavior" either (it's just poorly named =P). And std::remove_if() would provide more opportunities for the compiler to intelligently optimize, wouldn't it? Because it iterates from beginning to end, while *guaranteeing* to the compiler that no funny business is going on, unlike manually iterating. (i.e. the same optimization benefits *range-for()* has over regular *for()*)

Comment: bobobobo: The problem is that your algorithm is slow for vector. Each `erase` will shift the remaining elements down by one. If you're erasing 50 elements out of 1000, that's ~50,000 moves, where you only needed ~1000 moves of the survivors to their final slots.