# Why can't I delete list object in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, list, algorithm, object

I tried my best to figure this out but it was unsuccessful :C

PROBLEM

```
for (Treniruote& t : treniruotes)
            {
                if (t.data == duotaData)
                {
                    if (t.laikas == duotasLaikas)
                    {
                        treniruotes.remove(t);
                    }
                }
            }
```

FULL CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

struct Treniruote
{
    string data, laikas, vardas, pavarde, pratimai;
};

void NuskaitytiIsFailo(list<Treniruote>& treniruotes)
{
    string line, word;

    fstream file("planas.csv", ios::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            stringstream str(line);

            Treniruote row;

            if (getline(str, word, ','))
                row.data = word;
            if (getline(str, word, ','))
                row.laikas = word;
            if (getline(str, word, ','))
                row.vardas = word;
            if (getline(str, word, ','))
                row.pavarde = word;
            if (getline(str, word, ','))
                row.pratimai = word;

            treniruotes.push_back(row);
        }
    }
    else
        cout << "Could not open the file";
}
void rastiKlientoInfo(list<Treniruote>& treniruotes)
{
    int a;
    string fname, pavarde;
    
    cout << "Write clients surname:";
    cin >> pavarde;

    cout << "Output to the screen press -1\n";
    cout << "Output to the file press - 2\n";
    cout << "Output all exercise needed to be done in a week - 3\n";
    cout << "Your choice:";
    cin >> a;

    if (a == 2)
    {
        cout << "Enter the file name: ";
        cin >> fname;
    }
    else if (a == 3)
    {
        cout << "Enter the file name: ";
        cin >> fname;
    }
    else
    {

    }


    for (Treniruote& t : treniruotes)
    {
        if (t.pavarde == pavarde)
        {
        
            if (a == 1)
            {
                cout << t.data << endl;
                cout << t.laikas << endl;
                cout << t.vardas << endl;
                cout << t.pavarde << endl;
                cout << t.pratimai << endl;
                cout << endl;
            }
            else if (a == 3)
            {
                fstream file(fname + ".csv", ios::app);
                file << t.pratimai << endl;
            }
            else 
            {
                fstream file(fname + ".csv", ios::app);
                file << t.data << endl;
                file << t.laikas << endl;
                file << t.vardas << endl;
                file << t.pavarde << endl;
                file << t.pratimai << endl;
                file << endl;
            }
            
        }
    }
}

void PakeistiReiksmes(list<Treniruote>& treniruotes)
{
    string duotasLaikas, duotaData;

    cout << "irasykite norima data ir laika ,kada norite pakeisti duomenys" << endl;
    cout << "data(formatas(XXXX.XX.XX)):";
    cin >>duotaData;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "laikas(formatas(XX:XX-XX:XX)):";
    cin >>duotasLaikas;


    for (Treniruote& t : treniruotes)
    {
        if (t.data == duotaData)
        {
            if (t.laikas == duotasLaikas)
            {
                t.vardas = t.pavarde = t.pratimai = "obolys";
            }
        }
    }
}

void SukurtiTuscius(list<Treniruote> &treniruotes)
{
    for (int i = 27; i <= 30; ++i)
    {
        stringstream diena;
        diena << "2022.11." << i;
        for (int j = 8; j <= 19; ++j)
        {
            stringstream valanda;
            valanda << j << ":00-"<< j+1 <<":00";

            Treniruote t;
            t.data = diena.str();
            t.laikas = valanda.str();
            t.vardas = t.pavarde = t.pratimai = "nera";

            treniruotes.push_back(t);
        }
    }
}

void ParodytiVisaTvarkarasti(list<Treniruote>& treniruotes)
{
    for (Treniruote& t : treniruotes)
    {
        cout << t.data << endl;
        cout << t.laikas << endl;
        cout << t.vardas << endl;
        cout << t.pavarde << endl;
        cout << t.pratimai << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void salinti_pridėti(list<Treniruote>& treniruotes)
{

    
    
}

void ProgramosPabaiga(list<Treniruote>& treniruotes)
{

    fstream file("planas.csv", ios::out);

    for (Treniruote& t : treniruotes)
    {
        file << t.data <<","<< t.laikas << "," << t.vardas << "," << t.pavarde << "," << t.pratimai;
        file << endl;
    }
    cout << "PROGRAMA BAIGTA";
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    int choice;

    bool gameOn = true;

    list<Treniruote> treniruotes;

    struct tm newtime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    localtime_s(&newtime,&now);

    auto month = to_string(1 + newtime.tm_mon);
    auto day = to_string(newtime.tm_mday);
    auto hour = to_string(newtime.tm_hour);
    auto hour_pridėta = to_string(1 + newtime.tm_hour);

    //sukuria .csv faila pagal irasyta pavadinima
    //string fname;
    //cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    //cin >> fname;
    // fstream file(fname + ".csv", ios::app);
    
    //Menu
    while (gameOn != false) {
        cout << "*******************************\n";
        cout << " 1 - Create empty weekly plan.\n";
        cout << " 2 - Show the full schedule.\n";
        cout << " 3 - Read the weekly work plan.\n";
        cout << " 4 - Change the schedule field information.\n";
        cout << " 5 - Find the given client's full weekly workouts\n";
        cout << " 7 - Exit.\n";
        cout << "*******************************\n";
        for (Treniruote& t : treniruotes)
        {
            if (t.data == "2022." + month + "." + day)
            {
                if (t.laikas == hour + ":00-" + hour_pridėta + ":00")
                {
                    cout << t.data << endl;
                    cout << t.laikas << endl;
                    cout << t.vardas << endl;
                    cout << t.pavarde << endl;
                    cout << t.pratimai << endl;
                    cout << endl;
                }
            }

        }
        cout << "*******************************\n";
        cout << " Enter your choice and press return: ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            SukurtiTuscius(treniruotes);
            break;
        case 2:
            ParodytiVisaTvarkarasti(treniruotes);
            break;
        case 3:
            NuskaitytiIsFailo(treniruotes);
            break;
        case 4:
            PakeistiReiksmes(treniruotes);
            break;
        case 5:
            rastiKlientoInfo(treniruotes);
            break;
        case 6:
        {
            string duotasLaikas, duotaData;

            cout << "irasykite norima data ir laika ,kada norite pakeisti langeli" << endl;
            cout << "data(formatas(XXXX.XX.XX)):";
            cin >> duotaData;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "laikas(formatas(XX:XX-XX:XX)):";
            cin >> duotasLaikas;

            for (Treniruote& t : treniruotes)
            {
                if (t.data == duotaData)
                {
                    if (t.laikas == duotasLaikas)
                    {
                        treniruotes.remove(t);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            break;
        case 7:
        {
            ofstream file;
            file.open("planas.csv", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc);
            file.close();
            ProgramosPabaiga(treniruotes);
            break;
        }
        default:
            cout << "Not a Valid Choice. \n";
            cout << "Choose again.\n";
            cin >> choice;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your "PROBLEM" description is a code dump. It says nothing about what the problem is. Also, don't post the full code. Post a [mre] where you've removed everything but the part you actually need help with.

Comment: Thou shalt not modify the list thou iterate. At least not with a range-based `for`. Removing the item breaks the book-keeping that's being hidden out of sight.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088495/how-to-remove-all-even-integers-from-setint-in-c/2088542#2088542

Comment: Here's another [Can you remove elements from a std::list while iterating through it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596162/can-you-remove-elements-from-a-stdlist-while-iterating-through-it)

Comment: TL;DR version: You can't do this with range-based-`for`. Range-for is fantastic for simple iteration, but it falls all over itself when you want to do anything complicated.  You need to drop back to old-school iteration and update the iterator (or index) manually.

Answer (score 2):

You must not remove items from a list while iterating through a range-based for loop. Under the hood, the loop stores a `begin` and `end` iterator of the original list, and iterate all items between them, and attempting to remove items during the loop will make `end` unreachable.

Instead, you could simply use [`std::list::remove_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) to remove all elements that satisfy a certain condition:

```cpp
my_list.remove_if([a, b](const auto& element){
    return element.a == a && element.b == b;
};
```